# C# SteamWriter: How to Create multiple text files and write to them?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, office-interop

I'm working on an extension for office using Interop assemblies, as part of this extension the primary goal of an exe I am building is to export PPTX slides as individual images.

I also want to create a text file that would contain some info on each slide. I am able to export the slides. I also create one text file but nothing is written to it. Each file should export as 1.txt, 2.txt...

```
class {
static void ConvertAndExportImagesAndTextFiles(ARGS){

//Some stuff that reads and prepares the slides for the export method
//Loops and exports several "objSlide" after taking args

  foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.PowerPoint.Slide objSlide
                                        in objActivePresentation.Slides)
{
 i++;

string PathAndNumber = string.Concat(FilePath, i);
string PathAndNumberWithExt = string.Concat(PathAndNumber, ".txt");

 FileStream fs = new FileStream(

                     PathAndNumberWithExt ,

                     FileMode.OpenOrCreate,

                      FileAccess.ReadWrite);

                StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs);
                try
                {
                    sw.WriteLine("Howdy World.");
                }
                finally
                {
                ?????????
                }

  objSlide.Export(FilePath, format, res, res);

    }
```

I'm sorry, I am lost... The slides export because they are indexed by PowerPoint, But do I need to incmnt something here?

Comment: If you tried the answer and it worked for you, you can mark it as "accepted" using that little checkmark next to it, as a thank-you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just put your FileStream and StreamWriter into a `using` clause. The problem is that your writes are buffered, and until you call `Close` (or have `using` do that for you), that buffer remains in memory, and doesn't get written out.

```
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(new FileStream(...)))
{
    sw.WriteLine("Howdy World.");
}
```

As pointed out by the commenters, though, you might want to use a shorthand:

```
using (var sw = File.CreateText(...))
{
    sw.WriteLine("Howdy World.");
}
```

Comment: Flush will also force it to write to the file.

Comment: @Brad that's right, though that's not a good reason to skip the `using` clause.

Comment: @romkyns - Yes and no. If the stream is only used in the local method then the using statement is great. However, if I wrap some functionality and have a Stream as a class member, I might want to choose when to flush that stream. Using is not just a silver-bullet.

Comment: Understandable, Thank you very much

Comment: @Brad Sure, but unless the file is open for the entire lifetime of your program, you'd better call `Close`. Unless you intentionally want to keep it locked according to your `FileShare` parameter (which defaults to disallowing even read access).